# How to edit my pictures to get this look?

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, effect, editing

I’m a wedding photographer and there is this beautiful creamy sort of dull look on some pictures I saw. I’ve been practicing and practicing to get the same look but I have not been able to. Could I have some help please?[image]

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?"
questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and
edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, 
too. Thank you!

Comment: Is it the reduction of the yellow that you like? Or the lifting of the highlights? Or perhaps the whitening of the whites? Maybe even the matting of the blacks. Is it possible to provide more information?

Comment: Also related: [What's the best way to ask a "How do I achieve this effect?" question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: I'd say you have to have very bright, diffuse, even lighting, use a long lens and wide aperture to isolate the subjects and heavily blur the background, achieve excellent focus, and use models that have been carefully made up with motion-picture matte makeup to get exactly that look. Then you won't have to do much editing.

Comment: Is the picture you attached your desired result? or is it your photo that you want to edit? 

If that is your target I think its because of the lens they used. Is not that just a portrait picture with background blur?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is an already token photo, and you want to edit it.

I had used the 'Picsart' application in phone, and i saw 'Ivory' effect which is a free effect, which could make such things, i mean keeping red lights while trying to increase contrast of photo and make black areas smoothed (i think). but before using ivory effect, you should make background blured. there are bluring tools in photoshop, also exist in Picsart app. A tip for bluring: the more time you spend on precision of borders of the main subjects, the better result you will get.

As an example, i downloaded following photo (excuse me for low resolutions):
[image]
Then i started with Color Splashing tool in Picsart, means that i removed all colors but those near to Red. Then i decreased 'HighLight' and increased 'Shadow' and finally increased Contrast. This is result (However it is not fairly similar to what we expected):
[image]

Once again, i applied the effect 'BRNZ 4' which seems that makes photo Bronzing as its name. This effect seems better, and following is the result.
[image]
There are better effects (paid ones) that you may find them better, but i am using a free version so you must try it yourself.

Comment: The blur here is almost certainly due to using a (relatively) large sensor and a fast lens, not computational.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That very well may be true, but the OP asked how to *edit* their photos to achieve a similar look.

Comment: @morteza It would be quite helpful if you could include an example before and after edit shot for demonstration. Thank you.

Comment: @travelgasm I added an example.

Comment: @morteza Great; hope the OP finds this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a wedding photographer, one way to learn it nowadays might be to let AI do it the same with your photos.

You might upload photos in your Lightroom catalogue to [imagen-ai.com](https://imagen-ai.com/), choose a style from their profiles and you'll get your catalogue back post-produced in that style and you can see the Lightroom sliders, tone-curve and settings for each photo.

They have enough photos free for you to learn.

It's not 100 % reliable, it's good to learn theory, but some AI post-produced photos will be good and an advantage is that you'll see how to do it with your photos.

(I'm not affiliated with the company, I just like that AI is being used for such thing.)